# Css Chrome zoom breaks layout

Tags: css

zooming in on chrome dispositions elements by >= 1px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, by zooming in on divs which are a set size, you're not guarenteed to get a fixed size back from zooming in on them, and your layout must be very tight and unforgiving if your layout breaks

Comment: yeah.. i just added my own zoom feature.